# How to set up Facebook Log In For Business in my Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have created an app on Facebook that requires users to log in with their Business account, as I need to call some business-related APIs to provide service for them.

But I found that after my business account gets verified and everything gets settled, logging in with that app still send me to the page showing that "It looks like this app isn't available".

Then I tried again on private mode. This time, it gives me a different error message:

"Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app as we are updating additional details for this app. Please try again later."

Is there something I should fix on my side in order to be able to log in in my app? The account I am using has a related business account so it should not be the issue.

PS. I tried with another app that uses client log in (not business log in), and that one works perfectly.

Comment: You have to specify the scope permissions of your app in your login request (es. email,public_profile,.. )

Comment: I'm also having a similar issue. Also even when my authorization page shows up it doesnt include all of the business accounts. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @pnadolny No, I ended up forcing the user to log in for themselves (personal account) for now.

Comment: @TerryWindwalker are you using the marketing ads api product? I'm not able to find a way to let user authorize my app even as themselves. Theres a few threads in their dev forums that I'll link https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2473733426168558/ and https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/909248303756096/